# How can I read a txt file using python

Tags: python, file, txt

**data.txt**

I want to read this file using python.

Answer (score 5):

```
f = open('path/to/file.txt')
content = f.read()
f.close()
```

Comment: To ensure that a resource is cleaned up when the relevant code block finishes, (also in case an exception is thrown) it is recommended to use the `with` keyword: `with open('path/to/file.txt', 'r') as f: ....content  =  f.read()`

Answer (score 1):

## writing to file

```python
file1 = open('data.txt', 'w')
file1.writelines("hello world")
file1.close()
```

## reading a file

```python
file1 = open('data.txt', 'r')
Lines = file1.readlines()
```

if you dont understand feel free to ask me a question.

Answer (score 1):

The **with** decorator below will automatically close the file when it's done.

```
with open("data.txt", encoding='utf-8') as file:
    my_data = file.read()
```

If using runtime, be sure to include the four spaces before the second line, and press Enter another time to end the **with** statement before typing **my_data** to confirm the variable contains the text from the file.

Your session will look like this:

```
>>> with open("data.txt", encoding='utf-8') as file:
...     my_data = file.read()
... 
>>> my_data               
'This is the text in the file'
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `with open() as`, as given below

```
_file = 'temp.txt'

with open(_file, 'r') as fyl:
    ct = fyl.read()

#do something
```

This has the added benefit that the file is closed even is an exception occurs, so it's good practice to use `with open() as`.